# Github - Octopus Deploy Integration

Tags: github, octopus-deploy

Basically i have the following scenario that i need to solve:

On a schedule basis, OctopusDeploy is pulling the latest releases from code repo using GitHub Feed and then perform some operation through the tentacle agent on another server.

Problem:
Currently we have to trigger a release in Github manually whenever there is changes to the repo so that Octopus Deploy can pick up new changes. Is there a way to trigger the release in GitHub automatically whenever there is a merged event to the master.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to guess that you don’t want to expose your Octopus Deploy instance to the internet... so how about use reoccurring scheduled deployments?

https://octopus.com/blog/octopus-release-2018.4#recurring-scheduled-deployments

Comment: i will give that a try. thanks for the suggestion. I won't mark it as an answer yet as i haven't had a chance to try it.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently we have to trigger a release in GitHub manually whenever there is changes to the repo so that Octopus Deploy can pick up new changes.
> Is there a way to trigger the release in GitHub automatically whenever there is a merged event to the master.

First, since March 2022 (4 years later):

> ### [Octopus Deploy is now a GitHub secret scanning partner](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-18-octopus-deploy-is-now-a-github-secret-scanning-partner/)
>
> GitHub secret scanning protects users by searching repositories for known types of secrets.
> By identifying and flagging these secrets we help protect users from data leaks and fraud associated with exposed data.
>
> We have partnered with **[Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/)** to scan for access tokens for their cloud-hosted product, Octopus Cloud.
>
> Octopus API keys allow users to perform tasks like creating and deploying releases. We'll forward access tokens found in public repositories to Octopus Deploy, who will notify the affected user via email

In that new context:

- no need for an external private Octopus Deploy
- The check would be done for any new commit

But this is limited to secret scanning, so it might not do everything you were doing in your case.